# The RowDataBound events of the gridview is not fired after turning to the next page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use a gridview to display the search result. After clicking search button, the gridview will show page 1, but when I click page 2 link, the gridview disappeared and it was back when I click search button again and show page 2's content.

here is my code

```
 <asp:GridView ID="searchresult" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" AllowPaging="true" OnRowDataBound="searchresult_RowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="searchresult_PageIndexChanging" 
             HeaderStyle-BackColor="#f9e4d0"
             HeaderStyle-Height="20px"
             Font-Size="11px"
             AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#cfdfef"
             Width="800px" style="text-align:left">
   </asp:GridView>
```

and code behind

```
protected void search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      List<someclass> totalResult = new List<someclass>();
      ..... //some code to generate the datasource

      searchresult.DataSource = totalResult;
      searchresult.AllowPaging = true;
      searchresult.DataBind();
 }

protected void searchresult_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
}

protected void searchresult_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
      searchresult.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
      DataBind();
}
```

I have no idea why the page 2 won't show up until I click search button again. when I clicked the page 2 link, the page did postback but the RowDataBound event was not fired

Comment: Can you show the `Page_load` method?

Comment: Sounds like the data isn't being reloaded to me.  Can you post the logic in the `DataBind()` method call in searchresult_PageIndexChanging, or is that the DataBind() method on the page?

Comment: @Khan there is no code in Page_load

Comment: @pita Then we at least need to see your `DataBind` method.

Comment: @BrianMains I have a strong feeling `DataBind()` is being incorrectly used, isn't a method he wrote, and is just running [DataBind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5e5992d.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give your grid a datasource. It appears you are only doing this on `search_Click`, so your grid is only going to have data then. Try something like:

```
protected void search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PopGrid();
}

protected void searchresult_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    searchresult.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    PopGrid();
}

protected void PopGrid()
{
    List<someclass> totalResult = new List<someclass>();
    ..... //some code to generate the datasource

    searchresult.DataSource = totalResult;
    searchresult.AllowPaging = true;
    searchresult.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

searchresult_PageIndexChanging event handler will make that functionality work.  However I recommend you use a gridview control inside a Panel with vertical scroll bar.  My user love it and it is a lot faster moving up and down the gridview without defining any page index changing.

I hope it work for you.